# GridFS and FindOne based upon file metadata

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I've got some additional details stored in a files metadata. I'm trying to figure out how to query this out using the c# official driver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

database.GridFS.FindOne(Query.EQ("metadata.WhatsMyName",new Bson.BsonString("Chriss")));